# Group concat the column names from the table based on their row values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple field names whose value in the rows can be 'no'/Null/'yes'. Now I need to get the concatenated field names of all the fields whose row value is 'no'.

Consider my table

`id` `field1` `field2` `field3`
`1` `no`  `yes`      `no` 
`2`  `yes` `no`       `no`

Then I need the output though MySQL as

`id`   `fields`
`1`   `field1,field3` 
`2`    `field2,field3`

Is it possible?

Comment: If you have tried to develop a solution on your own, please show it.

Comment: @pintxo I tried but am not xactly getting the above result solely through mysql, which I expect, rather I'm involving php to get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `CONCAT_WS` function(will return a concatenated string containing only those fields where values are `'no'`):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    CONCAT_WS(',',
              IF(`field1` = 'no', 'field1', null),
              IF(`field2` = 'no', 'field2', null),
              IF(`field3` = 'no', 'field3', null)
    ) AS fields
FROM  `your_table`
```

> **CONCAT_WS()** does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any *NULL* values after the separator argument.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: Thanks buddy @RomanPerekhrest !
that resolved the issue post some alterations :)

Answer (score 0):

The below query resolved my issue perfectly.

SELECT 
    id, 
    CONCAT_WS(',',
              IF(`field1` = 'no', 'field1', null),
              IF(`field2` = 'no', 'field2', null),
              IF(`field3` = 'no', 'field3', null)
    ) AS fields
FROM  `your_table`
Where 'no' IN (field1,field2,field3);